# floatingActionButton (SpeedDial library)

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, horizontal-line

How can I open SpeedDial in a horizontal way in my project like this?

[image]

If there are other libraries, that is fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimum-reproducable-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create your own custom floating action button. But since you are open to packages too writing an answer in which you can achieve it using a package

Try https://pub.dev/packages/custom_floating_action_button

Add this to pubspec.yaml

```dart
custom_floating_action_button: ^0.0.3
```

You can wrap the scaffold with CustomFloatingActionButton

```
//add custom floating action button on top of your scaffold
//minimum 2 and maximum 5 items allowed
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomFloatingActionButton(
      body: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('appbar title'),
        ),
        body: Container(),
      ),
      options: const [
          CircleAvatar(
            child: Icon(Icons.height),
          ),
          CircleAvatar(
            child: Icon(Icons.title),
          ),
         //All widgets that should appear ontap of FAB.
      ],
      type: CustomFloatingActionButtonType.horizontal,
      openFloatingActionButton: const Icon(Icons.add),
      closeFloatingActionButton: const Icon(Icons.close),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you know how to add list of FAB if I want to create my own floating action button?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/expandable-fab this should give you a better idea of creating custom FAB